# How to draw the Hasse diagram of the following poset?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Which are the minimal and maximal elements?

The poset is: $(\{\emptyset,\{{\emptyset,1 \},\{1\}},\{1,2\}\},\subseteq) $

I assume, that it will look like a vertical chain, at the first stage from below with $\emptyset$, the second, $ \{\emptyset,1 \} $, the third $ \{1\}$, and the last one which is at the top of the chain will be $\{1,2\}$.

How could I draw Hasse-diagram with latex, is my solution correct in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have
$$(\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset, 1\}, \{1\}, \{1, 2\}\}, \subset)$$

At the very bottom we should have $\emptyset$ because
$$\emptyset \subset \{\emptyset, 1\}$$
$$\emptyset \subset \{1\}$$
$$\emptyset \subset \{1, 2\}$$

Then we have $\{1\}$ which should be straight up from there (nothing else at that level)
$$\{1\} \subset \{\emptyset, 1\}$$
$$\{1\} \subset \{1, 2\}$$

after that, we have two maximal elements $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{\emptyset, 1\}$

The lines should look like this:

\ /

|

Comment: I appreciate your fast answer, and can I say that $\emptyset$ is the minimal element?

Comment: yes, it is the minimal and the minimum (there's no maximum because there's two maximals and maximums must be unique).